# How can i reformat dates

Tags: python, django, chart.js

Hey guys i receive my data from oanda and plot it via django in charts.js

```
class ChartData(APIView):
    def get(request, *args, **kwargs ):


 data = oanda.get_history(instrument='EUR_USD',  # our instrument
                             start='2016-10-01' ,  # start data
                             end=time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),  # end date
                             granularity='D')  # minute bars  # 7
    df = pd.DataFrame(data['candles']) # 8

    data50 = oanda.get_history(instrument='EUR_USD',  # our instrument
                             start='2016-10-01',  # start data
                             end='2017-01-01',  # end date
                             granularity='D')  # minute bars  # 7
    df50 = pd.DataFrame(data50['candles']) # 8

    data200 = oanda.get_history(instrument='EUR_USD',  # our instrument
                             start='2016-6-01',  # start data
                             end='2017-01-01',  # end date
                             granularity='D')  # minute bars  # 7
    df200 = pd.DataFrame(data200['candles']) # 8

    history = df['openBid']
    date_labels = df['time']


    history = df['openBid']
    date_labels = df['time']

    data = {
             "history": history,
             "date_labels": date_labels,
        }

    return Response(data)
```

Now the dates are formatted as you may see in the screenshot.
How can i format the dates in the following format DD/MM/JJJJ?

Thanks in advance

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tphVV.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you pass the response data into your template, you can format your dataframe, as the `oanda` will return the `time` with format `2014-02-12T14:50:25Z`, you can format the `df['time']` with fomat `DD/MM/YY`.

```
df['time']=pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

After formatting, `2014-02-12T14:50:25Z` will become `02/07/2014`.